# Help with Unity global illumination removes cel shaded effect

Tags: unity, shaders, cel-shading

So I am using this toon shader I got from the asset store that supports global illumination. However it seems like the global illumination destroys the cell shaded effect, [and when in shadow it looks no different from the standard shader](https://streamable.com/2zonkr). Could anyone who is knowledgeable about shaders weigh in on what I could do in this situation? Thanks so much!

Comment: The usual "toon shaded" look is having one flat colour between the highlight and shadow. By adding smooth colour variation in the area outside the direct light highlight, you're removing that flatness. What do you want it to look like instead?

Comment: Basically I just want my toon shaders shadow and highlighted colors to be affected by the indirect lighting in my scene. So if I let say go into a cave I would want the colors to get darker based on the lighting. Thats why I tried to implement global illumination.

Comment: I also too a short capture of some BOTW gameplay do you see how the highlight and shadow colors are different depending on if hes being hit by the sun or not? In unity if hes not in the direct light he is completely shadowed. This is the exact effect I want so desperately :/

Comment: Sorry forgot to link the capture but here's the effect I'm talking about: https://youtu.be/r2JtSXXY_WY?t=310

Comment: This doesn't look anything like global illumination or light probes to me. It looks like Link is lit by two versions of the sun light, one dimmer but non-shadowcasting so it still gives him a distinct highlighted side even when he's in shadow. In both cases his colours remain fairly flat outside this discrete directional highlight band.

Comment: Oh that makes much more sense! Thank you. That can be accomplished pretty easily in Unity. But how do his shadow colors change, they get less vibrant when he's out of the sun, just like his highlights? Do you think this is a setting in the shader, or is it done with code?

Comment: Want to edit your question to include side-by-side comparison images so we can see exactly what you mean, and ask how to achieve that effect?

Comment: Ya that would be a better idea thank you I will do that.